# Defining multiple types in Typescript with JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am importing a JSON file with values being different types. The JSON looks like this:

```
  "l157Logo": "l157.svg",
  "l157": [],
  "l2Logo": "l2.png",
  "l2": [
    {
      "businessName": "Bricklayers Allied Craftworkers Local 2 NY/VT",
      "website": "www.bac2nyvt.org",
      "phone": "518-456-5477",
      "logo": null
    },
    {
      "businessName": "Bricklayers Allied Craftworkers Local 2 NY/VT Joint Benefit Funds",
      "website": "www.bac2funds.com",
      "phone": "518-456-0259",
      "logo": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I made a type that looks like this:

```
type unionsJSONSType = {
  [key: string]: {
    businessName: string;
    website: string;
    phone: string;
    logo: string | null;
  }[] | string;
};
```

In my limited understanding of typescript, I am saying that the value can be either an array of objects or a string. That makes sense to me but not the compiler.

I am assigning the type like this:

```
 const unionsFile: unionsJSONSType = unionsJSONS;
 const unionLogo = unionsFile[`${union}Logo`];
```

And when I try to map over it like this:

```
    {unionsFile[union].length > 0 &&
                unionsFile[union].map((provider, index) => {
                  return <SPBusinesses provider={provider} index={index} />;
                })}
```

This is the error I am getting:

````
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'```
````

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is very strict on what you define. Your usage of that type must never break, regardless of whether or not it is a string or an array. `map` will break if it is a string. Notice that both arrays and strings have a `length` properly, TypeScript doesn't say anything. But only one part of your union definition has a `map`. Thus you have told TypeScript that you are running the risk of a compilation error.

Handle the situation properly with an explicit check for an `Array`.

```js
// proper check for array
{Array.isArray(unionsFile[union]) &&
unionsFile[union].map((provider, index) => {
    return <SPBusinesses provider={provider} index={index} />;
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the part that causes the issue:

```js
unionsFile[union].map
```

`unionsFile` is of type `unionsJSONSType`, which means it's an object whose values are either arrays or strings. `unionsFile[union]` tries to access a field on `unionsFile`—namely the field that `union` evaluates to.

Depending on the field, the corresponding value might be of type "array," but it might also be of type "string." Since strings don't have a `map` property, TypeScript complains—rightly so, for you might be trying to call `map` on a string, which will throw an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you are making an union type of an Array and string and then try to access a method which is only available for Array. In short it looks like this:

```js
const data = [['arr'], 'str']
const foo: string[] | string = data[0]
foo.map(x => x)
```

Now Typescript knows that it is either an array or a string. With this knowledge it can't guarantee that there is a `map` method. Possibly it's a string and this would fail at runtime. Therefore it complains that the `map` method does not exist on this type.

---

I see two solutions to this problem:

1. Use `Array.isArray` to assure it's an array

```js
const data = [['arr'], 'str']
const foo: string[] | string = data[0]
if (Array.isArray(foo))
  foo.map(x => x)
```

2. Rewrite your type definition so that it must be an array

If you know that specific keys in your json contain arrays you could define that in the type.

Comment: Is TypeScript smart enough not to show type-related warnings by detecting in the code whether one manually checks for "array-ness" at runtime?

Comment: Typescript has [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), which are functions that assure that a variable is of a specific type. If I'm not mistaken, `Array.isArray` is a predefined one (aside `typeof`, `instanceof` and probably some others). If you are in a branch where this check returned true, typescript knows that it must be this of type.